# Best way to do Payment integration in Mobile Platform?

Tags: iphone, ipad, e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal

Today's world is mostly converted to mobile platform from the desktp platform and most of the payment trasaction, purchase and ecommerce facilities available via mobile applicaitons.

So, What is the best way to do payment integration in mobile application specially in iPhone, iPad, Android, Blackberry and Windows platform? There are plenty of third party API available out there but which one is the secure method to do paymaent gateway for mobile application development.

(1) For iOS platform we have inApp Purchase but it takes almost 30% to the apple and owner will get only 70% of the payment. Still there are some limitations are there as we can't provide the physical goods and services via inApp Purchase.
(2) Paypal is the secure method of payment gateway and it is also implemented in many of the mobile applications.
(3) Direct credit card payment option is also great one to use.
(4) There are many third party APIs available out there.

So, Here for mobile application development which is the best method to use specially for iOS platform like iPhone and iPad application that can be easily approved by apple without any problem.

Comment: The main thing for the mobile application developers today is the applicaiton shoulb be approved without any problem. As apple has its own guideline for the appstore upload procedure.

Comment: Will Apple approve the apps that are using payment system other than their own (inAppPurchase)?
Becoz I read on a link that it rejects such apps.here is the link
http://www.marco.org/2011/02/21/subscriptions-and-the-new-in-app-purchase-requirement

plz I have doubt for this..please clear it!

Answer (score 1):

We have two APIs for payment integration with iOS apps. The first uses app to app integration where transaction data is sent from the developer's app to our payment app. The other API allows developers to seamlessly integrate our payment app functionality into their app. Both APIs allow for easy approval by Apple and removal of the PCI-DSS compliance burden. For more info you can start here: http://developers.moblized.com/.

Update: We'll have similar APIs for Android by April 15, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in app purchases, they HAVE to use Apple's API or else your app will be rejected.

The only way to (sort of) get around it is to have the purchase be on a website and it will unlock something on your app. You can't link to the website from your app though so it's kind of useless if you don't already have users visiting your website. This is how the Kindle app does it since Apple forced the use of their in-app purchase API.

Comment: You can (and have to) use PayPal's API for iOS if you want to facilitate in-app purchases for physical goods. Apple's ToS specifically stipulates that their service cannot be used for physical goods.

Comment: So, What is the best way to use payment integration in iPhone.